# Solaris PHP OCI8 Outbound Port Usage

Tags: php, solaris, port

We are going to be using PHP/OCI8 to connect to a remote Oracle Instance.  My problem is the need to define the outbound port usage from PHP so the firewall rules that need changed will allow the data transfer back from Oracle.

Anything run outbound with PHP has variable port usage in the 50000 range.  Have seen from 50000 - 53500 so far.

That wide of a range will not fly with the firewall team.  How can I go about defining a singular port (or defined range of ports) for PHP/OCI8 to use??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused why the outbound port makes a difference.  For most all applications, only the destination port is "well known".  For example, you might make dozens of connections to port 80s all over the world, but your outbound (source) port will be almost at random.  I can't fathom a firewall policy that would place any importance on the source port.

Comment: I am in agreement, my assumption was that the data flow back would traverse the existing connection not require additional rules around the originating port, but I am being asked for the specifics...  Thx for the reply.